# Suggest/Make Mapnik data corrections

Tags: mapnik

The Mapnik representation of the streets in my area are completely incorrect. Is there a way that I can correct them myself?  If not who do I contact to make corrections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://trac.openstreetmap.org using the "mapnik" component, which in this case refers to the main stylesheet osm.org uses (that is rendered with mapnik) but not the mapnik software itself.